# How to crop extra space on a webview when textzoom action?

Tags: android, android-webview

In my android application I am displaying html content in `Webview`.
As part of my requirement i need to increase and decrease textsize of
`Webview` content. For this i am using the below method.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(150);
```

**Problem description:**

After textzoom into `mWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(150)` full webview along with content will increase the size.
But when i textzoom out to `mWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100)` then webview height still remain same as 150.
So it is displaying extra space after my content with textzoom 100.

Please advice me how to reset or crop the extra space in `Webview` content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Hope it will help .

Once the page finishes loading, I am injecting a javascript method to callback me JS hook. And in this method I am passing the size of .

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height) {
    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dharmishtha. Tried your suggestion but when it is not displaying full content when i zoom in. Some of the content is hidden from the visible portion.

Comment: Thanks again for your clue. After resetting layoutparams of my webview it is working as per my expectations. Called the following code everytime when i am performing textzoom operation. 'webView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));'